# jquery Check if hidden fields have values

Tags: jquery

I have dynamic fields and want to check if the values have been set, cant seem to get it work, no errors, but nothing seems to log. (please note I have other hidden fields on the page, I need to only validate the ones that start with ItemId_)

```
<div id="List">
<row id="row_bb0acd1a-b1e8-6f8c-88ea-324432339176">
<input type="hidden" id="ItemId_bb0acd1a-b1e8-6f8c-88ea-324432339176">
</row>
<row id="row_aaaaa-b1e8-6f8c-88ea-31223333">
<input type="hidden" id="ItemId_aaaaa-b1e8-6f8c-88ea-31223333">
</row>

</div>
<button type="button" onclick="Validate()")Next</button>

function Validate()
{

 $.each($('#List').find("input[name^='ItemId_']"), function (key, value) {
                console.log(value);
                console.log(key);
                if (value.length == 0) {
                    alert('Please ensure you select a item from the list');
                    return false;
                }
}
```

Comment: you look for name^= but the input only has id

Comment: if you are in control of generating HTML, you could also add class to those inputs and  avoid complex selectors. `$('.someClass')` is much more readable and expressive than `$("input[id^='ItemId_']")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for elements with a `name` attribute starting with `ItemId_` while your inputs doesn't have the `name` attribute.
You can change it to `id` in the jquery script or change the `id` attribute to `name` in the elements

```js
function Validate() {
  $.each($('#List').find("input[id^='ItemId_']"), function(key, value) {
    console.log(value);
    console.log(key);
    if (value.length == 0) {
      alert('Please ensure you select a item from the list');
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="List">
<row id="row_bb0acd1a-b1e8-6f8c-88ea-324432339176">
<input type="hidden" id="ItemId_bb0acd1a-b1e8-6f8c-88ea-324432339176">
</row>
<row id="row_aaaaa-b1e8-6f8c-88ea-31223333">
<input type="hidden" id="ItemId_aaaaa-b1e8-6f8c-88ea-31223333">
</row>

</div>
<button type="button" onclick="Validate()">Next</button>
```

Comment: doh!, been looking at for too long and it was staring me in the face!